# How to prevent this transitionend event from running twice/multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, transition

I want to check when a transition ends, but it fires twice / multiple times, I want to check only one time when I click the element and call the function, and not again when remove the class, I tried with `one()`, `stopPropagation()` or even `return false` at the end of the function but it didn´t work, how achieve that?
Here is a example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".main", function() {
        $(this).addClass('example');
        checkEndTransition()
    })
    
    function checkEndTransition() {
        $(document).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", ".main", function() {
            $.when($(this)).done(function() {
                console.log("Finished")
                var val = $(this)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    val.removeClass("example")
                }, 1500)
            })
        })
    }
})
```

```css
.main{
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.example{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #7fff7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: It calls it three times because you are animating 3 elements - width, height, and background color. It calls "transitionend, webkitTransitionEnd ect." for each one when they finish

Comment: Also your `$.when(this).done(...` logic is redundant

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".main", function() {
        $(this).addClass('example');
        checkEndTransition();
    })
    
    function checkEndTransition() {
       var flag = true;
        $(document).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", ".main", function() {
if(flag){
            
            $.when($(this)).done(function() {
                console.log("Finished");
                var val = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    val.removeClass("example");
                }, 1500)
            })
          }
         flag = false;
        })
    
  }
})
```

```css
.main{
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.example{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #7fff7f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Your problem is `$(document).on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", ".main", function()` runs multiple time. You can use a flag to make it run only one time. Use above script and it will work.

Comment: Then it never works again when the element is shrunk down again - although the this may be the OPs goal.

Comment: Yes this is what Im looking for, but why it runs multiple times if I call it only once?

Comment: As @jesus mentioned in the comment it might runs multiple times because you are binding transition event with main div and there are multiple transitions occurs on main DIV. Does my answer solved your problem?

Comment: @SmitRaval thank you for giving me credit. My solution below works btw...

Comment: @SilverSurfer if this answer has helped you, Please mark it as approved so in future it can help someone else. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It calls it three times because you are animating 3 elements - width, height, and background color. It calls "transitionend, webkitTransitionEnd ect." for each one when they finish.

To avoid this, instead of using transitions, use a keyframe object instead.

I also change the checkEndTransition() function to listen for animation end now instead of transition end...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".main", function() {
    $(this).addClass('example');
    checkEndTransition()
  })

  function checkEndTransition() {
    $(document).on("animationEnd webkitAnimationEnd", ".main", function() {
      $.when($(this)).done(function() {
        console.log("Finished")
        var val = $(this)
        setTimeout(function() {
          val.removeClass("example")
        }, 1500)
      })
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.main {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.example {
  animation: change 1 3s ease;
  -webkit-animation: change 1 3s ease;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0% {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
  50% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #7fff7f;
  }
  100% {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
}

@keyframes change {
  0% {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
  50% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #7fff7f;
  }
  100% {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div>
```